# Errors when compiling Fremlin Measure Theory Tex Files

Tags: errors, compiling, latex3

I am a Window user. 
I downloaded mt5.2015.tar.gz (TeX files, 1108KB) from [Fremlin website](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt5.2015/index.htm) and compile vol5I.tex (one of the files in the tar.gz file).

However, there are a bunch of errors after compiling and I could not view the pdf. Below are a few errors that I encounter:

> (1) ! Undefined control sequence. \buffer@\fontdimen13 \tenex
>
> (2) ! Missing font identifier.\global
>   \newdimen\buffer
>
> (3) ! Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters.\global \newdimen\buffer

In the website, the author only discussed compilation problems for Linux but not Window.

Your help is appreciated if you can help me to get rid of those errors and compile the pdf.

EDIT: The following is code for vol5I.tex

> \input volwp.aux \mtlulustyle \luluvolumeno=5
>
> \hyphenation{Ra-de-ma-cher} \hyphenation{Sous-lin}
>
> %\leaveitout{ \input mt50I
>
> \varfrnewpage %\end %}
>
> \input mt51 \input mt511 \input mt512 \input mt513 \input mt514 \input
>   mt515 \input mt516 \input mt517 \input mt518 %\end
>
> \varfrnewpage %}
>
> \ifnum\pageno=1\iflulu\pageno=83\else\pageno=93\fi\fi \input mt52
>   \input mt521 \input mt522 \input mt523 \input mt524 \input mt525
>   \input mt526 \input mt527 \input mt528 \input mt529 %\end
>
> \varfrnewpage %}
>
> \ifnum\pageno=1\iflulu\pageno=184\else\pageno=209\fi\fi \input mt53
>   \input mt531 \input mt532 \input mt533 \input mt534 \input mt535
>   \input mt536 \input mt537 \input mt538 \input mt539
>
> \vskip 48pt plus 12pt minus12pt
>
> \input mt5Iconc
>
> \immediate\write0{\number\nquery  queries}
>
> \end
>
> %329 pages %lulu  "spine width" 2.30 cm

Comment: I guess people are hesitating to follow unknown links. But are you sure that this is the main tex file, i.e. does it start with `\documentclass`?

Comment: @marmot: No, it does not contain \documentclass.

Comment: @marmot: I tried compiling with \documentclass. It still gives me the same errors. I think the tex file that I compiled inputs other tex files.

Comment: I checked the files. According to `readme.txt`, they are plain TeX files. You can compile them  with `tex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See ["Compilation problems"](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/texproblems.htm):

> **The commonest error**
>
> is to try to compile with
>
> ```
>      latex volx.tex
> ```
>
> which will produce an error message along the lines of
>
> ```
>      ! Undefined control sequence.
>      l.479 \buffer@\fontdimen13 \tenex
> ```
>
> when the LaTeX compiler encounters a line which makes no sense to it.

The file is *not* written in the LaTeX format, but for *plain TeX* (`x`=`5I` or `5II`):

```
tex volx.tex
```

TeX Live does not have `dvipdf`, thus I had also to apply the changes, described in the next section of the cited page to get it work with `dvips` and `ps2pdf`.

1. Download [volwp.2016.aux.txt](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/volwp.2016.aux.txt) and replace `volwp.aux`.
2. Run plain TeX to get DVI files (`.dvi`):

   ```
   tex vol5I
   tex vol5II
   ```
3. Run dvips to get PostScript files (`.ps`):

   ```
   dvips vol5I
   dvips vol5II
   ```
4. Run Ghostscript to get PDF files (`.pdf`):

   ```
   ps2pdf vol5I.ps
   ps2pdf vol5II.ps
   ```

The result is `vol5I.pdf` and `vol5II.pdf`.

BTW, it does not make any sense to try running LaTeX, because the source files are *not* written in that language.

Comment: I see. How should I compile plain TeX? I apologize if my question is too simple, as I have no experience in dealing plain TeX.

Comment: @Idonknow On the command line, just use `tex` instead of `latex` (or `pdflatex` or `lualatex`).

Comment: Sorry. I do not follows what you mean by 'Run plain TeX.' How do I do that? Otherwise, can you generate the two pdf files and send them to me?

Comment: @Idonknow On the command line, run `tex vol5I` instead of `latex vol5I`.

Comment: @Idonknow ... and convert the dvi file to pdf with `dvipdft vol5I.dvi`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Where is command line? Do you mean the place where I key in latex code?

Comment: @Idonknow See ["Command Prompt/cmd.exe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), ["How to use the Windows command line"](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm).

Comment: I use the command prompt and input 'tex vol5I'. But it returns 'I can't find file vol5I'. Please advise.

Comment: @Idonknow You have to go into the directory (folder) where this file is.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: After I input 'tex vol5I,' command prompt displays 'I can't find file miniltx.'

Comment: @Idonknow Then download it. The link is on the [cited page](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/texproblems.htm), for example. Or download it from [CTAN:macros/plain/graphics/miniltx.tex](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/graphics/miniltx.tex).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Wow, it works perfectly now. I obtained the two pdf already. Thanks so much for your patience and guidance.